# Как прикрутить к сайту эмоджи?

Tags: jquery, emoji

Вопрос на засыпку. Как прикрутить к своему сайту emoji ?

Есть сайт на php с mysql в кодировке utf8mp4 , jquery присутствует.

Есть textarea куда хотелось бы чтобы юзер вставлял эмоджи при наборе текста

Как вывести на экран браузера в div все эти картинки и чтобы по нажатию на них они вставлялись в поле textarea?

Чего то гугловство не очень помогает, т.к. не могу понять сам принцип

может быть есть где готовые примеры, чтобы посмотреть как это работает?

Answer (score 1):

В сети много библиотек для этого.
Ткк отмчено, что используется джиквери, запрос: "jquery emoji picker"

Пример: http://wedgies.github.io/jquery-emoji-picker/demo.html

Answer (score -2):

вот такую нашел либу https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker
хорошее описание, попробую ее использовать